# Calling a function to show text on select change

Tags: jquery, ajax, dropdownbox

I want to call a jQuery function to show this text (Dropdown):

```
<select name="filter" data-userid="3" onchange="getPoints(this.value)">
    <option value="one">One</option>
    <option value="two">Two</option>
</select>";
```

My query should looks like this:

```
function getFilterOption() {
    $(this).html(Dropdown)
    success: function(result){
        $("#Target").html(result);
    }
};
```

How can I do that? I just want to **show** the dropdown (*Beginners question*)

Comment: Why are you escaping quotes? i.e. `\"`

Comment: It's not clear at all what you're trying to achieve. `this` inside the `getFilterOption` function will be the `window`, not the `select`. Where is `Dropdown` defined, and what is it? Why is there a `success:` function defined in the middle of nowhere?

Comment: I just updated the post. I just want to show this dropdown with calling the function getFilter. De dropdown will call the function getPoints on onchange.

Comment: to show the hidden select box you just need to call `$("select[name=filter]").show();`. Thats it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a little tip, it would be a good idea to get away from using the inline code which you're using to do the `onChange`. You're using `JQuery` so use it's ability of doing the check for changes of dropdown.

Here an idea of what you can do:

(This is if the select box isn't already added to page, you append it to the page)

```js
$( document ).ready(function() 
{
     getFilterOption();
  
     $(document).on('change', "select[name*='filter']" ,function() 
     {
       getPoints(this.value);
     });
});

function getPoints(result) 
{
   $("#Target").text(result);
};

function getFilterOption() 
{
   $("#filterWrapper").append('<select name="filter" data-userid="3"><option value="one">One</option><option value="two">Two</option></select>');
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="Target">PlaceHolder Text</div>

<div id="filterWrapper">

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. There is another problem. Everytime I use the dropdown, I get another filter dropdown. How can I solve this problem?

Something like: if the select box already added to page, don't call the function getFilterOption,